# class being Annotated by @componenet can't have non Autowired fields

Tags: java, spring

I want to create bean, but it tells me you can't have field of type string or other type those their class declaration not include anotation @Component.
ex .

```
@Component
public class MyDependancy {
  private String name;
  MyDependancy(){}
  MyDependancy(String name){this.name = name }
  // setter and getter of name field

}
```

it show compiler error : Could not autowire. No beans of 'String' type found.
when I add @Autowired before declaration of name String, is give the same compiler error.

Comment: you can `@Autowire` only fields that you have previously declared as components, e.g. with `@Component`. Please read some basic tutorial on Spring

Comment: Spring don't know what's name to use when creating MyDependancy Bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your bean explicitly in the configuration. You don't need any autowiring inside your class:

```
public class MyDependancy {
  private String name;
  MyDependancy(){}
  MyDependancy(String name){this.name = name }
  // setter and getter of name field

}
```

And in the `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public MyDependancy myDependancy() {
  return new MyDependancy("Hello");
}
```

And then, from anywhere you can call to (this is just for example, please use setter\c'tor autowiring):

```
@Autowired
private MyDependancy myDependancy;
```

You can inject the `name` property in other ways as well.

Answer (score -1):

It should work in the latest version of Spring as this behaviour is mentioned in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-constructor-resolution) as follows :

> Similarly, if a class declares multiple constructors but none of them is annotated with @Autowired, then a primary/default constructor (if present) will be used.

As your example shows you do define a default constructor , so it should be used to create `MyDependancy` bean.

So I believe you are using an old version of Spring , most probably a version before 4.3 ?

Comment: I think OP was trying to annotate a String attribute with `@Autowired`

Comment: Don''t know. he just mentioned he try the codes he posted in the question and it returns this error. Then he try to add `@Autowired` , it also have the same error. So the original intention is that he does not plan to add any `@Autowried` , and just ask why the codes he posted does not work

Comment: I agree with you, I test it in spring 5 and doesn't get any error, if you don't have default constructor, then you get that error, but with the default constructor, you must not, check your spring version.

Comment: @MohamadMirzadeh Thanks for your support. But it is pity that  some nonsense guys do not try to really understand the question and my answer and give me downvote..